# How to create ChatRooms with Flutter/Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How do i go about creating chat groups where :

1- users can only join 1 group at a time.

2-that means users will not be able to see anything from that group without joining.

3- and useres have to exit existing group to join another.

4 also that means whatever been shared by users in that group will persist after user existing.

So I'm trying to create a session like functionality, but i have no idea how to implement that, any ideas?

Comment: this is quite big want to move to chats? or i can help you with a call also can you show your code how far you now?

Comment: I'm new at this, my knowledge is limited.. I learn as i go that's why i started this

Comment: its okay so did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, i have no idea how to implement that ,, lol,

Comment: Here's my gmail "a.chil6663@gmail.com" contact me io might help u then we go discord or gmeet

Comment: i emailed you..